# Display a layout as item in GridView

Tags: android, xml, layout, gridview

[image]

this image shows the layout of what i want to achieve, the black squares are images from the drawable folder, the red square is a framelayout with 2 images on top of one another. the problem is this : 
[image]

the red square (the framelayout) doesnt appear. See code below...

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

i got this fine working code from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) and it worked fine im my program, the thing is i wanted to change some item in this line :

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
    R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
    R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
    R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

i changed `R.drawable.sample_2` to `R.layout.some_layout`

here is the `some_layout.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/imagebehind" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/frameimage" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

all item from the line below appears :

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
  R.layout.some_layout, R.drawable.sample_3,
  R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
  R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

except for the `R.layout.some_layout`.

Comment: this   `R.layout.some_layout` and what you need is to provide a drawable. So its wrong

Comment: is there a way that i could use a layout instead of drawable items? @Raghunandan

Comment: you can inflate a custom layout for gridview items but you can't replace the drawable with the layout like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.grid_item,null,false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return convertView;
        }

        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.layout.some_layout, R.drawable.sample_3,
                R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
                R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
        };

        class ViewHolder {
            ImageView image;
            Button button;
        }
    }
```

Comment: tnx @Haresh , but the framelayout is still not appearing, what you did is you just placed a button in the item. but thanks tough :)

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.example.sampleproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView imageView;
        Button button;


        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.someLayout, null);
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        } else {

        }
        button.setText("some text");
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Friend it easy to inflate the layout : Read tutorials base adapter it will be useful